# What Terminator movie or series has Arnie locked out of a blast room while two teenagers survive?

Tags: episode-identification, the-terminator-series

I saw a *Terminator* film or episode where on one day the machines turned on people. At the end two teenagers were locked in a blast room and Arnie did not make it.

Comment: Not to be unwelcoming but there are 4 Terminator movies with Arnold Schwarzenegger. I'm surprised you wouldn't find that information in good faith.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like the end of [*Terminator 3*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines) (2003) except they're not teenagers they're in their 20s-30s.

Comment: Thank you  i could not remember if they were kids or not and the  trailer of number 3 did not jog any memories.  Thanks for answer. I am 51 years old, so not a spring chicken on this stuff. Xxx

Comment: @JudyDale please accept this answer as correct.

Comment: It could just as easily be Terminator Genisys as that has Sarah and Kyle are locked in a bunker

Answer (score 1):

That would be **Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines**. It was meant as a direct sequel to **T2: Judgment Day**. Those weren't teenagers, but 20-somethings; a young John Connor who had been essentially hiding from his destiny as the moral/practical leader of the Resistance we would see later in **Terminator: Salvation**, and his wife. The Arnold Terminator was a T-800 that was battling the more advance TX, the first seen female Terminator played by Kristina Loken.